# Poisson approximation to binomial distribusion question

Tags: probability

Suppose a sharpshooter's probability of missing the target on each shot is
only 0.01. Find the probability that she will miss the target 2 times from 200
shots
by using Poisson approximation to binomial distribution

Comment: No. I don't want. Sorry.

Comment: @Harold You do not want to "suppose" or you do not want to "find"? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letn $X$ have binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. If $n$ is large, and $p$ is small, and $np$ is of smallish size, then $\Pr(X=k)$ is well-approximated by $\Pr(Y=k)$, where $Y$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda=np$.

In our case, $\lambda=2$.

Recall that $\Pr(Y=k)=e^{-\lambda}\dfrac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.